# Gamemaker Studio 2 window_set_fullscreen() causes entire screen to go gray, CRTL ALT DEL doesn't work

Tags: game-maker, fullscreen

I'm working on a small game in Gamemaker: Studio 2 in which the user can press F11 to toggle fullscreen. In the "Key Press - F11 Event, I've added the following code:

```
if window_get_fullscreen()
{
    window_set_fullscreen(false);
}
else
{
    window_set_fullscreen(true);
}
```

This code works fine to toggle fullscreen two or three times, but after a few toggles the entire screen goes gray. I have attempted multiple times to use `CTRL+ALT+DEL` to close the game window, but nothing happens once the screen has gone gray. Is there something that I am doing wrong? I've checked the [documentation on fullscreening](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/windows%20and%20views/the%20game%20window/window_set_fullscreen.html) and it has the exact same code as I have.

Comment: Something else I've discovered: this issue occurs only when I use one monitor. If I use two monitors with one extended display, there is no issue.